# PHP integer to floating value

Tags: php

The database I am working with has price value as `1500` which is 15.00 or `2000` which is 20.00. The right two number will be floating decimals. Is there any PHP function to convert this kind of integer values `1500` to floating values `15.00`?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Not a function, an operator: it's called division, and most of us learned it in mathematics at school

Comment: You should do: `Number/100`

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be by using

> [number_format](http://php.net/manual/en/function.number-format.php)

like

```
number_format($price/100,2,'.',',');
```

where `$price` is the price.

Comment: `number_format` returns a string, not a float as was asked.